# Winterbash 2014 - Do we participate?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

[Winterbash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015, and the Community Team needs to know if we wish to participate or not. It is completely optional, but a fun little competition between all the participating sites during the Winter Holiday season.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “**I hate hats**” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, **all hats will go back into storage**.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

This year, it is operating as an **opt-out** event - If sites do not respond to the Community Team, it will be enabled for the sites. Any objections?

Comment: "Opt In" means that if you do not reply, then you will be **excluded** from the event. This contradicts your statement that "if sites do not respond to the Community Team, it will be enabled for the sites". That is a description of an **Opt Out**. Which is it?

Comment: did you mean to ask on [Freelancing.se]?

Comment: Yeah… we did it last year, and so we will do it this year. I don't believe a Meta post is needed.

Comment: @Sathya Already did, figured I had the template already, and I'd just do a copy/paste

Comment: @slhck Understood, just thought I'd ask in the community (since I'm not a mod here, I didn't want to assume)

Comment: @allquixotic I meant to say **Opted In**, not just simply **Opt In**. Fixed

Comment: Yeah, altough the announcement sent to mods basically says that mods should just decide it for the community. I don't have a strong objection against this post, but I think it's not necessary.

Comment: So what is this (the link doesn't exist)?

Comment: @fixer1234 One that isn't up yet, but it's where you will eventually see all the hats you've earned.

Comment: [I have no strong feelings one way or the other](http://i.imgur.com/2AHWKb4.jpg)

Comment: @fixer1234 From last year: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Preserving for posterity: [Close voted as "primarily opinion-based"](https://i.imgur.com/hLkTQtI.png)

Comment: @fixer1234: terdon gave a slightly more illuminating description in [Do we like hats?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/3254/80216) on Meta U&L.

Comment: [featured] can be removed and [status-completed] added, since the Dec 1 deadline has passed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Yes, let's participate!**

Like you say, those who don't want hats can easily opt out of having them. It's a bit of harmless fun.

Answer (score 31):

[image]

Comment: A helmet is a hat of sorts.

Comment: I find your lack of hats disturbing. *heavy breathing*

Answer (score 2):

**No!**

Just because I don't like hats, nobody else should get to have them either. I'm such a spoilsport.

Comment: Hat haters have an "I hate hats" hide hats option.

Comment: @fredley That's sort of the point with this answer. This way, everyone who views this question has an answer that they can upvote, no matter which way they prefer (hats, no hats, or plain indifferent to hats). :)

Comment: @fredley Michale has given us a target dummy to hit with downvotes so we can feel good about supporting hats. Everyone knows that self-esteem is a zero sum game: you can only gain it by stealing it from someone else. Michael has graciously offered his to us. Folks, prepare your downvotes!

Comment: The answer is specifically designed to undermine the position it claims to support.  I want to downvote it, just because I dislike the rhetorical technique, but....

Comment: @BenBarden Considering that this answer is currently at +13/-13, it looks like you've been mostly successful in your voting campaign.

Comment: I want to downvote the answer but upvote the way it was answered.